# Basic matrices question

Tags: matrices

Wondering about matrices multiplication, how to exchange two colums by a matrice multiplication ? I don't see the way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: do you know about elementary matrices?

Comment: Tom75, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

Answer (score 1):

You (right) multiply by the matrix  deduced from the identity matrix by exchanging column $i$ and column $j$, namely:

- if $k\neq i,j$, then $a_{kk}=1$,$a_{kl}=0$ for $l\neq k$.
- if $k=i$ or $j$: $\,a_{ij}=1$, $\,a_{il}=0\,$ for $l\neq j\;$ and $\;a_{ji}=1,
  a_{jl}=0\,$ for $l\neq i$.